# Variational argument technique

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, calculus-of-variations

I'm a little confused by this proof. As far as I can see the idea is that the Rayleigh quotient should tend to $\lambda_1$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ by the choice of $f$, but I'm a bit confused why exactly that specific variation $f_\epsilon$ was chosen and what exactly is being done in the final step leading to the conclusion.

Thank you in advance.

[image: https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~fan/research/revised.html]

Comment: What's $\lambda_G$ and what's (1.2)?

Comment: $\lambda_G$ is just the smallest non-zero eigenvalue of the graph Laplacian, so it's the second smallest eigenvalue. (1.2) is basically just the definition of $\lambda_G$ as the the infimum of a Rayleigh quotient over the space orthogonal to the eigenspace associated with the smallest eigenvalue.